# How do I get Windows to open apps in dark mode?

Tags: windows-10, dark-mode

Everything that I open is blinding white when it loads up e.g. Chrome, Explorer, etc. Is there no support for these applications to load dark before opening? I'm not talking about dark mode in general. I have Chrome and Explorer in dark mode. It's just when any app initially opens up that it's white

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply a darker color palette across Windows 10 apps, here's how.

1. From the Start menu again, open `Settings`.
2. Tap `Personalization`, and then over on the left tap `Colors`.
3. Under the label Choose your default app mode, turn on the **Dark** button.

Answer (score 0):

There simply is no general support for this. It is up to the app/program to support this natively, and there no windows way to change it other than run the app, change it, and done.